# Forcing children type in react-typescript: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<T>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-proptypes

I am trying to type a react component such that it only accepts certain types of children.  The component is called `ItemGroup`, and it should only accept components (or arrays of components) called `Submenu` or `MenuItem`.  For now, let's say it can only accept a single `Submenu` as a child:

I define the `Submenu` component and props:

```
interface SubmenuProps {
  popupId: string;
}

export const Submenu: React.FC<SubmenuProps> = ({ popupId }: SubmenuProps) => {
  return <div>some stuff</div>;
};
```

And now I define the `ItemGroup`, and type its children to allow only `React.ElementType`s of `SubmenuProps`, or an array thereof:

```
interface ItemGroupProps {
  title: string;
  children: React.ElementType<SubmenuProps> | React.ElementType<SubmenuProps>[];
}

export const ItemGroup: React.FC<ItemGroupProps> = (props: ItemGroupProps) => {
  const { title, children } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <div>{title}</div>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

I try to actually use it as such:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ItemGroup title="something">
      <Submenu popupId="123" />
    </ItemGroup>
  );
}
```

On the use of `<Submenu />`, I get an error:

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<SubmenuProps> | ComponentClass<SubmenuProps, any> | ElementType<SubmenuProps>[] | ... 20 more ... | (ElementType<...>[] & ReactPortal)'.
  Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<SubmenuProps>[] & ReactPortal'.
    Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementType<SubmenuProps>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.ts(2322)
App.tsx(14, 3): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ItemGroupProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

#### [Codesandbox demonstrating the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-typed-children-62ruo)

I have done this type of thing before, i.e. forcing certain types of children, by using a `children: React.Elementype<ChildProps>` in the props interface for the parent.  Why am I getting an error here.  How can I type the `ItemGroup`'s `children` prop to only allow `Submenu`s and/or `MenuItem`s?

Comment: You should be using `React.ReactElement<ChildProps>` instead of `React.ElementType<ChildProps>`, but it doesn't successfully limit the children based on props (see the answers in the question linked as duplicate).